# How can I grant permissions to pg_catalog functions in Google CloudSQL Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, database-administration

I am using Postgres 14 in Google CloudSQL - our monitoring setup started running into an error about not having permissions to execute `pg_ls_waldir()`. I want to grant execute on that function to the role running the monitoring - but it looks like the owner of the function is `cloudsqladmin`, and I haven't figured out how to connect as that user or to grant execute on the function using a different user. Any ideas appreciated!

Connected to the database as the `postgres` user and ran

```
postgres=> grant execute on function pg_catalog.pg_ls_waldir() to "prometheus";
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_ls_waldir"
```

As suggested, I ran the following as `postgres`:

```
postgres=> CREATER user mysuperuser WITH REPLICATION IN ROLE cloudsqladmin LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypassword';
```

then logged in as `mysuperuser`.

```
postgres=> grant execute on function pg_catalog.pg_ls_waldir() to "prometheus";
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_ls_waldir"
```

The function is owned by `cloudsqladmin` instead of `cloudsqlsuperuser`, so I logged back in as `postgres` to try again:

```
postgres=> CREATE USER mysuperuser1 WITH REPLICATION IN ROLE cloudsqladmin LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypassword';
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers
```

Comment: `CREATE USER user WITH REPLICATION
IN ROLE cloudsqlsuperuser LOGIN PASSWORD 'secretpassword';`

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication#create-a-replication-user) help? Also, search for `pg_ls_waldir` on that page for details on usage.

Comment: Huh - turns out that `postgres` can run `pg_ls_waldir()`. And `postgres` can grant `cloudsqlsuperuser` to another user like `prometheus` (although it cannot grant `cloudsqladmin`). Unfortunately, we are using vault with dynamic roles, so when it tries to create an ephemeral `prometheus` user, it fails because it can't grant `cloudsqlsuperuser`.